# Sound and Badge in Firebase FCM

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase

In my iOS app I am integrating FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) and I am able to send Push Notification successfully, but I did not find any indication in FCM document for how to send "sound" and "badge" thing.

So, how can I do this? Or is it not supported yet (this may not be possible)?

Right now I am just sending device-to-device notification, i.e. there is no App server in between (I know that is not recommended but still I want to know the answer).

---

Edit:
This is not duplicate as indicated. I know how to send sound and message in normal Push Notif (i.e. using APNS) but i was not able to find anywhere in FCM these keys. But as my answer shows link where i find these keys.

Comment: Hi @Shubhank . My Question is different. I know how to send sound and message in normal Push Notification scenario. Like we have to set "sound" key for custom sound that is already in my app. Plus i for badge i can pas any count. But problem here is there is no such keys in FCM i.e. Firebase Cloud Messaging things. So my question is Firebase Cloud Messaging related.

Comment: This is indeed not duplicated and the only thread talking about FCM. Were you able to increase the badge number when a notification is received on iOS? How?